# AspNet.Identity Criando usuario com Role

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

É a primeira vez que estou trabalhando com Entity e Identity e estou confuso sobre como persistir meu usuario.
Basicamente tenho uma tabela Usuario, com varios relacionamentos com o banco e o Id int) tenho a tabela AspNetUsers do Identity e a AspNetRoles.

Estou tentando criar uma transação para garantir que não vou criar o AspNetUsers sem o Usuario e ainda sem adicionar a Role selecionada na View em um DropDown que chamei Perfil.

Tentei em meu UsuarioController o seguinte, na action create:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CriarUsuario(Usuario model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser identityUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.LOGIN,
                LOGIN = model.LOGIN,
            };

            using (GPSdEntitiesIdentity IdentityContext = new GPSdEntitiesIdentity())
            {
                using (var transaction = IdentityContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(IdentityContext);
                    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

                    IdentityResult resultado = userManager.Create(identityUser, model.SENHA);
                    if (resultado.Succeeded)
                    {
                        resultado = userManager.AddToRole(identityUser.Id, model.Perfil);
                        if (resultado.Succeeded)
                        {
                            if (GravarNaTabelausuario(identityUser.Id, model))
                            {
                                transaction.Commit();
                                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ErroIdentity", resultado.Errors.FirstOrDefault());
                }
            }                
        }
        ViewBag.ReadOnly = false;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Sendo que o código que persiste na minha tabela Usuario é:

```
public bool GravarNaTabelausuario(string IdUsuario, Usuario model)
    {
        UsuarioEnt UsuarioEnt = new UsuarioEnt()
        {
            IdAspNetUsers = IdUsuario,
            IdPessoa = model.UsuarioEnt.IdPessoa,
            IdStatusRegistro = model.UsuarioEnt.IdStatusRegistro,
            IdUnidade = model.UsuarioEnt.IdUnidade,
        };
        UsuarioNeg UsuarioApp = new UsuarioApp(null);
        if (UsuarioNeg.RecebeRegistro(UsuarioEnt))
        {
            if(UsuarioNeg.ValidaRegistro())
            {
                if (UsuarioNeg.GravaRegistro(UsuarioEnt))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }            
        return false;
    }
```

Porém só funciona se eu comento as linhas referentes a criar a transação rollback etc. Com a transação como está estou tendo um erro de tempo limite de conexão atingido. Parece que a transação está bloqueando a tabela impedindo que os demais insertes e consultas de validação sejam executados. Alguém consegue identificar onde estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de vc ter instanciado a classe GPSdEntitiesIdentity, o UserStore e o UserManager não usam esse objeto nem o objeto transaction que vc criou.. então esse trecho de código está sendo meio que ignorado. 
A classe UserStore abre e fecha uma conexão no momento do comando, e a sua classe de negócio deve fazer a mesma coisa. 

O ***[TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx)*** pode ajudar no que vc precisa.

Veja se resolve... se não resolver avisa.

Comment: Obrigado Will! Vou dar uma olhada!